# partial loading of image when ever application is opened

Tags: android, html, angularjs, cordova

Hi I am developing a cordova application. I nearly have 3000 PNG images.I built an apk file and tested in various android device.In few mobile images are loaded but In few mobiles few images are skipped and only few is displayed.This is my html code

```
<ul>
<li><span style="background-image: url(export/animals/386688127-1.png);width:29px;height:29px;"></span></li>
<li><span style="background-image: url(export/animals/386688127-2.png);width:28px;height:28px;"></span></li>
<li><span style="background-image: url(export/animals/386688127-3.png);width:29px;height:28px;"></span></li>
<li><span style="background-image: url(export/animals/386688127-4.png);width:23px;height:32px;"></span></li>
<li><span style="background-image: url(export/animals/386688127-5.png);width:34px;height:29px;"></span></li>
<li><span style="background-image: url(export/animals/386688127-6.png);width:27px;height:26px;"></span></li>
<li><span style="background-image: url(export/animals/386688127-7.png);width:29px;height:33px;"></span></li>
<li><span style="background-image: url(export/animals/386688127-8.png);width:37px;height:27px;"></span></li>
<li><span style="background-image: url(export/animals/386688127-9.png);width:26px;height:29px;"></span></li>
<li><span style="background-image: url(export/animals/386688127-10.png);width:26px;height:25px;"></span></li>
<li><span style="background-image: url(export/animals/386688127-11.png);width:29px;height:25px;"></span></li>
<li><span style="background-image: url(export/animals/386688127-12.png);width:26px;height:27px;"></span></li>
<li><span style="background-image: url(export/animals/386688127-13.png);width:34px;height:24px;"></span></li>
<li><span style="background-image: url(export/animals/386688127-14.png);width:29px;height:29px;"></span></li>
<li><span style="background-image: url(export/animals/386688127-15.png);width:26px;height:30px;"></span></li>
<li><span style="background-image: url(export/animals/398942398-1.png);width:30px;height:29px;"></span></li>
<li><span style="background-image: url(export/animals/398942398-2.png);width:26px;height:28px;"></span></li>
<li><span style="background-image: url(export/animals/398942398-3.png);width:32px;height:30px;"></span></li>
<li><span style="background-image: url(export/animals/398942398-4.png);width:30px;height:29px;"></span></li>
<li><span style="background-image: url(export/animals/398942398-5.png);width:23px;height:31px;"></span></li>
.................
</ul>
```

I dont use any Js in specific to display this images.I am using AngularJS. I could not find what exactly the problem is. Am I wrong someway? Can someone Please help me?

Comment: are all image files of same size ? might be problem of image size

Comment: no it is different sizes is there any solution?@HardikVaghani

Comment: can you try with same source in same number of images ?

Comment: you mean single folder?@HardikVaghani

Comment: maintain same no. of `li` but assign same source.

Comment: Sorry Do you want me to have a single image with 3000 li? Am I right? @HardikVaghani